# Good websites/books for geometry exercises?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, triangles

I'm looking for exercises similar to those seen on putnam exams or olympiad exams, such as finding the area of polygons inscribed other polygons, finding certain angles, etc.

Comment: Many good problems can be found at [artofproblemsolving.com](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [Go-geometry](http://gogeometry.com/problem/), which covers the basics up to IMO level.

I'm not too certain what you would consider Putnam Geometry, in part because the undergraduate competitions don't focus heavily on Euclidean Geometry techniques, but have more to do with calculus ideas.

Comment: I haven't a single clue about any geometry and figured the geometry found in "A primer for mathematics competitions" would be a good place to start (and it's great).